# How to serve a static file depending on req.params in Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have to return a single audio file out of few from server and use it in the frontend. I have tried multiple ways to filter a single audio file using express.static, but none of them seem to be working.

Here is an idea of what I am attempting to do:

```
app.get('/:songName', (req, res) => {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/music/' + req.params.songName);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `res.sendFile()` method for returning an audio file. Assume we have a song under requested name:

```
app.get('/:songName', (req, res) => {
    // sendFile argument should be an absolute path (Like yours):
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/music/' + req.params.songName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the correct `express.static( ... )` settings? I mean your `app.use` declaration is inside your request handler method. It should be outside:

```
app.use( middleware );
app.get( request_handler );
```

Also, it's good practice to place all your static files into a dedicated folder and use it like that:

```
app.use('/music', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'music')));
```

[Doc here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)